# Is there a word for something hidden in pants/trousers pocket but its shape is visible?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

How do I describe the shape that is visible from the exterior of a pocket? For example, when we put a cell in our pants pocket, we can ‘see’ it is a cell phone.

How do I express this in a sentence? Is there a standard phrase, expression or idiom which describes this situation?

> I can see the thing he's hiding in his pocket as the thing's shape was visible

I'm sorry if the sentence is a bit incorrect, but I am not able to construct a better one.

Comment: 'Is that your phone or are you just happy to see me?'

Comment: umm what? I didn't get you?

Comment: @KunalBisht That quote can easily be looked up on Google. Scroll down to Mae West.

Comment: @Mr lister. I first googled it but no help. Might be i used wrong key words but a help in shorter time is always appreciated.

Comment: re V0ight & Mr Lister: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OrAreYouJustHappyToSeeMe

Comment: An apparent cellphone protuberance? The protuberance in his pocket was clearly a cellphone. Don

Comment: @V0ight Are you suggesting that 'Philosopher's Stone' is rhyming slang?

Comment: The most famous quote is from Mae West: "Is that a pickle in  your pocket or are you glad to see me?"

Comment: The question lacks evidence of research.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 23, accepted):

People often refer to the state you describe as one invovling ***bulging pockets***. [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=pocket%20bulge&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizl-KUitjNAhXFKyYKHVWSDH0Q_AUICCgB&biw=1280&bih=631) is a google image search of "pocket bulge" (but **beware**, the search also returns risque images of underpants).

Urban Dictionary even has an entry for "[back pocket bulge](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Back%20Pocket%20Bulge)," although they restrict it to the bulge caused by an overstuffed wallet.

***Bulge*** means

> Swell or protrude to an unnatural or incongruous extent ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bulge))

To describe the situation where a pocket bulge reveals information that someone is trying to keep secret, you might use the word ***betray***, which means

> Unintentionally reveal; be evidence of ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/betray))

An example sentence would be:

> "His bulging pocket betrayed that he had his phone."

---

You could also call such a bulge a ***telling pocket bulge***, where ***telling*** means

> revealing ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/telling))

An example sentence would be:

> "He had a conspicuous and telling pocket bulge."

Comment: Thanks Silenus. I hope I can upvote but don't have repo. Thanks once again. I can use it.

Comment: @KunalBisht You got the rep now. Also, did you know you can accept answers? This will mark them as such, which is helpful for everyone reading your question. It also awards bonus reputation to the answerer and you.

Comment: @KunalBisht Looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G8cLi.png). Next to the answer you want to accept.

Comment: @KunalBisht: You were shown [the site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) just a few days ago. Time to take it again!

Answer (score 15):

> I could tell that he had his cell in his back pocket by its **outline**.

The outline is just another word for contour, a hard solid object such as a cell, a bunch of keys or a man's wallet will produce a distinctive shape in a fairly tight-fitting pocket.

> **[outline](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outline)**  (Cambridge Dictionaries)
>    the main shape or edge of something, without any details:
>   *Underneath the hospital blankets I could see the outline of her poor wasted body.*

There's even a question about outlines on LifeHacks Stack Exchange
[How to prevent outline marks on trousers?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/4194/how-to-prevent-outline-marks-on-trousers)

There's also the term ***fading*** as reported on [Levis Strauss.com](http://www.levistrauss.com/unzipped-blog/2014/04/how-to-wear-jeans/)

> The **‘Stuff-in-Your-Pockets’** **Fading**: While the wallet fade has become as ubiquitous as lap fades and whiskering, a newer popular pocket accessory—the iPhone—has launched scores of message boards online both in celebration and condemnation of cellphone outlines being worn on to the front and back of jeans.

You could combine both words as this person did on [*Pinterest*](https://www.pinterest.com/fmj89/how-to-get-dressed-men/)

> Love it when a man's jeans have the **fade outline** of a wallet.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There isn't a word specifically for being able to see the shape of an object in a pocket, but the word ***silhouette*** means

> [the outline or general shape of something](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/silhouette?s=t)

One way to use it could be:

> Don't try to claim you forgot your wallet and can't pay; I can see the silhouette in your pocket!

Silhouette implies that you can see the outline of the object's shape very well and can discern what it is. You shouldn't use it to describe when you can tell someone has stuff in their pockets, but you have no idea what. For example, you *wouldn't* say:

> I know you have something in your pocket, because I can see the silhouette.

In that case, *bulge* would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

There is a word that is used when the object in question is a gun. It applies in a situation when the gun is supposed to be concealed (hidden) under clothing, but other people can determine that the object under a person's clothing is in fact a gun. In that case, people say that the gun "prints" or "is printing". This is a big discussion item among civilians who carry concealed weapons in US, due to legal requirements. See these examples: ["Can I get in trouble for my CC gun printing?"](https://thefiringline.com/forums/showthread.php?t=524546), ["I lose 10 lbs. and now my gun prints"](http://www.defensivecarry.com/forum/concealed-carry-issues-discussions/196066-i-lose-10-lbs-now-my-gun-prints.html) and ["Concealed Gun Printing?"](http://www.thehighroad.org/archive/index.php/t-43142.html).

Answer (score 2):

A seventy-five-cent word which you could use is *adumbration*, which is the noun form of the transitive verb adumbrate (ăd′əm-brāt′, ə-dŭm′-), which means

> [to outline; give a faint indication of](http://thefreedictionary.com/adumbrated)

An exemplar, using the word:

> I detected from his pocket the adumbration of a cellphone.

Or,

> The presence of a cellphone was adumbrated in his slightly protruding pocket.

For an interesting video, I recommend [this](http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=Adumbration%20Meaning&&view=detail&mid=D330C31DA6C08F080BBFD330C31DA6C08F080BBF&rvsmid=27F30CCAAE5203467BB927F30CCAAE5203467BB9&fsscr=0&FORM=VDFSRV) one.

Comment: I think you're overvaluing it.

Comment: Don't you mean he or she is "bestowing upon it an inflated pecuniary assignation"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: To be honest, I'm not that familiar with the valuation of words. Back in the day, an impressive word was worth fifty cents. Fifty years later, I thought adumbration would've increased in value by at least 50 percent! Gosh, 50 years ago you could buy a couple loaves of bread for fifty cents; today, four bucks a pop! Don

Comment: *Adumbration* is foreshadowing. Any outlining sense is likely to be figurative. I could be convinced otherwise by evidence, however. Do you have any examples of usage to mean partially reveal physically?

Comment: @Ivan: Not sure what adumbration has to do with filthy lucre, but I'm willing to be enlightened! (Unless of course you're referring to the valuation I placed on my suggested word. If that is the case, see my comment to Edwin, above. Don

Comment: @deadrat: No, but I'm workin' on it! Don

Comment: deadrat is right, *adumbration* really doesn't mean what the OP is asking for. It has much more to do with (light and) shadow, literal or figurative.

Comment: @LarsH: I think I'll stick to my guns here. Watching the video I provided a link to in my answer, I'm of the opinion that if "adumbration" does not yet mean the  outline of something hidden, then maybe it's time it does. Take the Latin root UMBR, for example. At one time, one of the words which derived from it--umbrage--had nothing to do with taking offense, but now it does. How about joining me in a grassroots effort to expand the meaning of adumbrate to include the outline of a weapon, cellphone, banana, or whatever, when said object is concealed behind clothing. Who's with me?! Don

Comment: Words certainly do change meaning over time, and I don't disagree with your proposal to expand the meaning of adumbrate. However the OP seems to be looking for ways to communicate clearly within the existing accepted and understood meanings of words.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a good word for it. Printing, as in "her weapon was less concealed than she thought as it printed through her thin shirt"

Comment: As far as I know, this word is used only when the context is a concealed firearm.

Answer (score 0):

May as well make my comment into an answer, considering "phrase-requests" is one of the tags in this question.

**Is that your phone or are you just happy to see me?** is a humorous modern adaptation of an old euphemism originating in the 30s:

[image]

The phrase is used in the context of a person's (usually a man's) pockets being so filled that they may be mistaken for something else, e.g. his private parts. Obviously it's been getting a resurgence in recent times due to the ungainly size of modern cellphones. The phrase works best when it's directed towards a male, but I suppose you could use it to a female as well for added laughs. Note: it's highly informal and may be offensive to some.

Modern usage of this phrase and its variants, [according to tvtropes.org](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OrAreYouJustHappyToSeeMe)